# How do I set a time zone for a crontab?

Tags: cron, timezone, debian-etch, utc

I would like to use UTC for the scheduling times in a crontab for a single user, regardless of the current time zone of the server. How do I do this on Debian Etch?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195818/change-the-time-zone-of-a-cronjob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set the variable `TZ` in `/etc/default/cron`. but this is the timezone for all crontabs.

another alternative is using fcron. the [documentation](http://fcron.free.fr/doc/en/fcrontab.5.html#FCRONTAB.5.TIMEZONE) shows an option to set the timezone in each crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Some cron installations use CRON_TZ to set the per-user interpretation of the crontab times.

Here's part of man 5 crontab on Centos 7:

`The CRON_TZ variable specifies the time zone specific for the cron table.  The user should enter a time according to the specified time zone into the table.  The time used for writing into a log file is taken from the local time zone, where the daemon is running`.

Default Debian uses a patched vixiecron, (per https://wiki.debian.org/cron)  and does not support per-user time zone functionality.  If you set a variable in the crontab, it passes to the child jobs, but does not affect the TZ of the parent cron job.  Debian has a 'cronie' package in experimental that supports the CRON_TZ functionality.

Comment: Haha. I love how Debian puts cronie in "experimental" when the rest of the Linux world has been using it for 10 years or more.