# Cronjob time delay

Tags: cron, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timezone for cron jobs](https://serverfault.com/questions/314697/timezone-for-cron-jobs)

On a VPS server, my cronjobs are running 3 hours late. The server current time is Tue Oct 11 23:56:09 EDT 2011 which is the time I want to (I checked this in WHM). However, the cronjobs still execute at pacific time (where the server is physically located).

I've asked my hosting provider for an answer, but I haven't had an answer for 48 hours. Do any of you have a clue how to solve this mastermind puzzle? By the way, the cron job is properly set (everything works fine, the only problem is the 3 hour delay from the time I put).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/107482/how-do-i-set-a-time-zone-for-a-crontab

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/314697/timezone-for-cron-jobs

Comment: add 3 hours to each cron job!

Answer (score 0):

It may be as a result of a discrepancy between the timezone that your OS is set to use and the timezone that your cronjobs are set to use. Check the user's crontab file to see if any specific timezone has been specified.

You can [change the `TZ` variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Timezone_handling) in crontab to be the timezone that you want the jobs to run as. BTW, here is the list of [TZ timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

This topic has also been explored in two other ServerFault questions:

- [Timezone for cron jobs](https://serverfault.com/questions/314697/timezone-for-cron-jobs)
- [How do I set a time zone for a crontab?](https://serverfault.com/questions/107482/how-do-i-set-a-time-zone-for-a-crontab)

Comment: Thanks, I sent your reply to the support, since I don't have access to crontab file. I'll wait and see their answer..