# Is it possible to make an individual daily cron run with UTC time while keeping the system localtime?

Tags: cron, utc

I have a cron script under /etc/cron.d as so:

> SHELL=/bin/sh
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
>
> 0 0     * * * root /usr/local/sbin/app_logrotate >> /var/log/app-newday.log

This works but it executes always at 00:00 local time. The app in question uses UTC time ( I cannot change this). In my time zone this is a few hours behind resulting in the date tag on the daily logfile this application creates never being a new day.
I can't change the system localtime to UTC as other applications depend on localtime.
I was wondering if it is possible to execute this cron only at 00:00 UTC while keeping my system localtime.
I have tried adding TZ=UTC to the cron script which did not work. 
Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Why not just delay the crontab with the time difference  ?
If you can't, change your crontab by a cronjob in /etc/cron.d which uses `date` with the right options to know if it's time or not.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/107482/how-do-i-set-a-time-zone-for-a-crontab

Answer (score 1):

In general the cron dameon will inherit the system's timezone. The only (easy) way I know is to set the TZ/CRON_TZ variable.

Did you restart the cron daemon after setting the TZ / CRON_TZ variable. This si required for cron to pick up the changes!

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations recognize a CRON_TZ variable to specify the interpretation of the crontab numbers.  `man 5 crontab` Centos 7 says:

`The CRON_TZ variable specifies the time zone specific for the cron table.  The user should enter a time according to the specified time zone into  the table.  The time used for writing into a log file is taken from the local time zone, where the daemon is running.`

While default Debian/Ubuntu says:

`The cron daemon runs with a defined timezone. It currently does not support per-user timezones. All the tasks: system's and user's will be  run  based on  the  configured  timezone.  Even if a user specifies the TZ environment variable in his crontab this will affect only the commands executed in the crontab, not the execution of the crontab tasks themselves.`

So, if your system respects it:

```
CRON_TZ=UTC
SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 0 * * * root /usr/local/sbin/app_logrotate >> /var/log/app-newday.log
```